# Google Workspace GMail API Create Label for impersonated account

Tags: google-apps-script, label, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am a Google Workspace Super Admin and have Domain-Wide Delegation and a Service Account setup.  Using Apps Script, I am trying to add a label to an impersonated user (which means that I cannot use the GMailApp client).  I have been successful in reading a message and removing a label from a message), so I am confident that I have permissions sorted out.

I am referencing the API here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/create

and following the model from here: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/Google.gs

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Adds a label to the account
 */
function addLabel(){

  USER_EMAIL = "my.test@domain.org"; // Set the user to be impersonated

  var service = getService_();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      },
      payload: {
        "name": "New Label",
        "messageListVisibility": "show",
        "labelListVisibility": "labelShow"
      }

    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  } else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
  }
  return "";
}

/**
 * Configures the mail service for the user to be impersontated
 */
function getService_() {
  return OAuth2.createService('GMail:' + USER_EMAIL)
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the name of the user to impersonate.
      .setSubject(USER_EMAIL)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
      // setup of domain-wide delegation.
      .setScope('https://mail.google.com/');
}
```

I always receive an error code 400, Invalid Request with a status of INVALID_PARAMETER. If I remove the payload, I no longer get the error (but of course it doesn't add the label).

Any ideas please?

Comment: can you show me how you are creating your access token

Comment: I'm using the Google library with id:  1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF  from here: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/dist/OAuth2.gs

Comment: For completeness, I've added the function in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what exactly was wrong with my initial code, but this is now working for me:

```
/**
 * Adds a label to the account
 */
function addLabel(){

  var data = {
    'name': 'New Label',
    'messageListVisibility': 'show',
    'labelListVisibility': 'labelShow'
  };

  USER_EMAIL = "my.test@domain.org"; // Set the user to be impersonated

  var service = getService_();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'method': 'post',
      'headers': {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      },
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload': JSON.stringify(data)

    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  } else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
  }
  return "";
}
```